# Hash(SHA2 -256) a column in a Avro File(coming as a flowfile) in Apache Nifi

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-nifi, avro, sha256

Avro files are coming from source as flowfiles in Apache Nifi and i want to fetch 'Password' column and hash it with 'SHA2-256' and give it as an output flowfile and finally put it in AWS s3.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can modify the content of an individual "column" of Avro data (or any record format in NiFi) with the [`UpdateRecord`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html) processor.
2. You should **not** be doing this. SHA-256 is a cryptographic hash function but it is **not** designed for nor safe for "password hashing". Taking passwords, running them through a single SHA-256 digest function, and putting them on an S3 bucket is a very bad and very unsafe idea. **Do not do it**. Research [how password hashing works](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) before implementing any password protection.